# iOS - Order of View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am going to try my best to explain what is happening, but please let me know if I can clarify further. I naturally have multiple view controllers and between them, I use segues to transition and transfer.  Below is the order of the views I am having an issue with:

- Edit Profile View; Select to See Current Address
- Current Address View shows. This view has back button (pops the view from stack)
- Back at Edit Profile View, I select to Update Current Address
- I select to save address and notified via UIAlert that save successful (reflected in backend). I click OK in UIAlert related to the following action:

  ```
  let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){
  UIAlertAction inself.basicMap.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myLocation")
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("backToEditFromWorkSegue", sender: self)}`
  ```

then I go back automatically to Edit Profile. If I click the Done button in Edit Profile view, the view disappears but the Update Current Address shows again. This is what I want to know why is happening and how can it be solved. The Done button on the Edit Profile is linked to this:

```
self.customNavigationBar.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Done, target: self, action: "addTapped")
```

and addTapped is:

```
func addTapped()
{
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

From what I can think about here, I believe something is going wrong with popping out the views.

Comment: You should take a look at [unwind segues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)

Comment: is the done button connected with a segue ?

Comment: @azimov no it isn't. only the lines above define it and how it works

Answer (score 1):

Your code will pop the current view controller off the stack and show you the previous view controller.  I think you are trying to get back to the root view controller? If so try:

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Comment: greentor, How do I know which is the root view controller?

Comment: Its the initial view you show in the navigation controller - its root view controller.

Comment: yes I tried it and it took me to the login view. That would not work in this scenario

Comment: You want to look at unwind segues the link by @adrianokw is useful